# Tracking depth in a breadth first search of a directed tree

Tags: python, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to find the distance between the root and the depth of the node that is being traversed, for example if I had a the following adjancency list representing the tree `{ 1: [2, 3], 2: [4], 3: [5]}`  an associated list like the following would be created `[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]` denoting the level of each node.

I have the following code and can't see where I'm meant to add counting functionality etc, ideally this would deal with cross and back edges as well

```
def bfs(graph, root):
    seen, queue = set([root]), collections.deque([root])
    visit_order = []
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        visit_order.append(vertex)
        for node in graph[vertex]:
            if node not in seen:
                seen.add(node)
                queue.append(node)

    print(visit_order)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of queuing just the nodes, you can queue the nodes and their levels as tuples, and when you enqueue a node it's always coupled with the current level plus one, so that when you dequeue a node and append the node to `visit_order` you also get the level of the node from the tuple:

```
import collections
def bfs(graph, root):
    seen, queue = {root}, collections.deque([(root, 0)])
    visit_order = []
    levels = []
    while queue:
        vertex, level = queue.popleft()
        visit_order.append(vertex)
        levels.append(level)
        for node in graph.get(vertex, []):
            if node not in seen:
                seen.add(node)
                queue.append((node, level + 1))

    print(visit_order)
    print(levels)
```

so that:

```
bfs({ 1: [2, 3], 2: [4], 3: [5]}, 1)
```

would output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought I had seen an implementation similar to this but couldn't figure out how to implement it, I will run a few tests on some graphs and mark as answered if all goes well, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dictionary to keep track of the current depths:

```
from collections import deque
d = {1: [2, 3], 2: [4], 3: [5]}
def bfs(graph, root = 1):
   queue, seen, depths = deque([root]), [], {root:0}
   while queue:
     val = queue.popleft()
     depths.update({i:depths[val] +1 for i in graph.get(val, [])})
     seen.append(val)
     queue.extend([i for i in graph.get(val, []) if i not in seen])
   yield seen, depths

[(_all, _depths)] = bfs(d)
print([_depths[i] for i in _all])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

---

The logic is simpler, however, when using a `class`, as a depth-first traversal can be applied:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, _start):
     self.__dict__ = {'head':_start, 'data':[Tree(i) for i in d.get(_start, [])]}
  def __contains__(self, _val):
     if self.head != _val and not self.data:
       return False
     return True if self.head == _val else any(_val in i for i in self.data)
  def get_depth(self, _val):
     if self.head == _val:
       return 0
     return 1+[i for i in self.data if _val in i][0].get_depth(_val)

t = Tree(1)
print([t.get_depth(i) for i in set([i for a, b in d.items() for i in [a, *b]])])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```