# How to track and show visited nodes that are in the same level?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-traversal

I have question about bfs algorithm on graph. As you can see from the picture below, i want to find the path from 'C' to 'L' and get all expanded nodes in the correct order. I get the correct result from the code shown below but i cannot find a way to track/show the visited node - which is node (D) and (H).

The solution i have in my mind so far is to get all nodes that are in the same level fist, then sort before putting it on the queue.

[image]

Note:

1. Tie-breaker is by alphabetical order : which i can achieve using itemgettere.
2. You can find the original code posted by blhsing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52513309/tracking-depth-in-a-bfs).

```
import collections
from operator import itemgettere

class graph:


    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.graph = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'B': ['A', 'F'], 'F': ['B', 'J'], 'J': ['F', 'K'], 'C': ['A', 'G'],
                      'G': ['C', 'H', 'K'], 'K': ['G', 'J'], 'D': ['A', 'H'], 'H': ['D', 'G', 'L'], 'L': ['H'],
                      'E': ['A', 'I'], 'I': ['E', 'M'], 'M': ['I']}

    def bfs(self, graph, root, goal):
        seen, queue = {root}, collections.deque([(root, 0)])
        visit_order = []
        levels = []

        while queue:

            vertex, level = queue.popleft()

            # Stop when the goal is reached
            if goal in visit_order:
                break

            visit_order.append(vertex)
            levels.append(level)

            for node in graph.get(vertex):
                if node not in seen:
                    seen.add(node)
                    queue.append((node, level + 1))

            # sort queue by level, then alphabetically
            temp_queue = list(queue)
            temp_queue.sort(key=itemgetter(1, 0))
            queue = collections.deque(temp_queue)

        print(visit_order)
        print(levels)


g = graph()
g.bfs(g.graph, 'C', 'L')

#output = ['C', 'A', 'G', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'K', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'L']
#[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: If I would have been in your place, I would have done depth first search instead. With each recursive call, add the node visited to a list to maintain the path so far. If reached last node, you have the path ready. If not, just pop the nodes from back in the list, and continue the search.

Comment: If you want to use bfs, enqueue the list of nodes on the path. Like queue entries would look like | {C,A}, {C, G} |.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, the graph does not have directions, so when you are at node 'A', its neighbors are actually {B, C, D, E}, instead of just {B, D, E}, unless you explicitly exclude the previous node 'C'.

I think the tricky part about this question is that you want to find out whether a node has been visited before, but also want to exclude the current node's previous's previous node which has definitely been visited.

I modified the sample code, shown as below.
I traverse the graph by level, so I don't need to track the level info explicitly, but I left it there in case it helps.

```
class graph:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.graph = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'B': ['A', 'F'], 'F': ['B', 'J'], 'J': ['F', 'K'], 'C': ['A', 'G'],
                      'G': ['C', 'H', 'K'], 'K': ['G', 'J'], 'D': ['A', 'H'], 'H': ['D', 'G', 'L'], 'L': ['H'],
                      'E': ['A', 'I'], 'I': ['E', 'M'], 'M': ['I']}

    def bfs(self, graph, root, goal):
        seen, currentLevel = set(), [(None, None, root)]
        visit_order = []
        level = 0 # you can use the level info if needed
        while currentLevel:
            nextLevel = []
            for v0, v1, v2 in currentLevel:
                if v2 not in seen:
                    visit_order.append(v2)
                    seen.add(v2)
                    for v3 in graph[v2]:
                        nextLevel.append((v1, v2, v3))
                elif v2 != v0:
                    visit_order.append(f"({v2})")
            level += 1

            # Stop when the goal is reached
            if goal in seen:
                break

            # all nodes in nextLevel are at the same level already. Just sort alphabetically
            currentLevel = sorted(nextLevel, key=lambda p: p[2])

        print(visit_order)

g = graph()
g.bfs(g.graph, 'C', 'L')
# output = ['C', 'A', 'G', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'K', '(D)', 'F', '(H)', 'I', 'J', 'L']
```